# make_heap vs priority_queue efficiency when needed once per frame

Tags: c++, sorting, std

I tried to find information about this particular use, but I could not.

In a simulation software (that acts like a video game), I'm building an event manager that prioritize the events based on a value submitted by the event creator. The event queue will be parsed once per frame and all the events within will be processed, so each new frame starts with an empty queue.

Now I have two options to store the events and have them prioritized:

1. Use a std::priority_queue, which will keep the list/vector/container prioritized at all time, then simply parse it when it's time;
2. Use a non-prioritized container and when I need to parse it, call make_heap on it just before so that it makes the event prioritized.

Since I'll be parsing the event list only once per frame, I don't *need* to have it prioritized at all time.

My question is: in this situation, is make_heap more efficient than to keep the container up to date at all time? Or does it depend on the amount of data that I'm managing? Or am I over thinking it?

Comment: Why do you want to use `make_heap` instead of a simple sorting (in case 2)? Does new events with new priorities arise while you process events?

Comment: If the number of elements is large compared to the number processed per frame, sorting would be more expensive than making a heap and popping the first several events.

Comment: @rutsky Good comment, I did not even considered that option; I guess that it would be even cheaper to sort them than to keep them sorted (by using sort rather than make_heap).

Comment: @MarkB The plan for now is to process each and every event that is in the queue each frame, that is, to empty the queue. We're kindof new to this so we don't know yet what amount of data we'll be processing. (Bad design? Maybe... there has not been a lot of though lately for ours software architecture, and I'm trying to improve it...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asymptotically there is no difference:

1. Inserting in ordered collection N times is O(N log N).
2. Sorting unordered collection of N elements is O(N log N).

So best way to select fastest solution is to implement both and check on real data.

I think storing events in container such as `std::vector` and sorting them at the end would be faster, because fast adding along with frame preparation will not invalidate CPU caches, that may occur during "long" and non-trivial O(log N) insert into `std::priority_queue` or `std::map`.

Also storing events in simple container (`std::vector`) and processing them when needed (sorting etc) looks more logical to me.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping the queue prioritized all the time needs `Θ(n log n)` time. Making the heap needs `Θ(n)` time. Later, both methods need the same time, `Θ(n log n)`, to extract the elements one by one in sorted order. So `make_heap` is clearly a better choice. But since both methods, when they are needed, are equivalent to sorting your input, `quicksort` is a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

`std::map<priority, event>` might be a tradeoff: do the insert based on priority. `std::map`'s insert is or order `n log(n)` and keeps it prioritised at all times.

At the time when the events are needed, no processing is needed, just iteration.

Comment: I'd have to use the multimap version, because many events can have the same priority. I guess that would add a bit more complexity.

Comment: Or use `std::map<priority, list<event>>`; keep a list of events of equal priority. That should work just fine too and won't add complexity.

Comment: Notice however that each element in a map is an allocation on its own (plus, it has to store other data besides the element itself), and all this does not come for free.